# last | reboot in linux rebooted the machine, can someone explain why ?

Tags: linux, unix

how does the pipeline work in the below?

```
last | reboot
```

The above rebooted the linux machine.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? It's hard to explain why it should because we don't know what you were expecting. What do you think the `reboot` command does?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

`last` search the *last logged in user* and `last` output is given to `reboot` and `reboot` will reboot the system.

```
last         |          reboot
 |                       |                 => process1 output will be input 
process1               process2                for process2
```

See the `man 1 last` it says

> Last searches back through the file /var/log/wtmp (or the  file 
>   desig‐
>          nated  by  the -f flag) and displays a list of all users logged in (and
>          out) since that file was created.

As Daniel says importantly, `reboot` doesn't care about its input. It probably doesn't read it at all, so piping something in doesn't change its behavior.

Comment: And, importantly, `reboot` doesn't care about its input. It probably doesn't read it at all, so piping something in doesn't change its behavior.

Comment: Okay @DanielH thats very useful info.